# Computed Property in Protocol Extension not giving desired result

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I am trying to implement Stack in Swift language. So, I made a protocol `Container` and inherited it in another protocol `Stack`, now to keep track of number of elements in stack I introduced a computed variable `count` in `Container` Protocol and gave it a getter in extension of `Container` protocol. (I could keep a track of number of elements by `arr.count`, but I am exploring other ways to do the same) At the end, I pushed one element in the stack, but when I print the value of `count` it was still 0, why the value of `count` is not 1?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

protocol Container{
    associatedtype Item
    var arr : [Item]{get set}
    var count : Int{get}
}

protocol Stack : Container {
    mutating func push(item : Item) -> ()
    mutating func pop() -> Item?
}

extension Container {
    var count : Int {
        get {
            return arr.count
        }
    }
}

struct MyStack<Element> : Stack {
    var count: Int
    
    typealias Item = Element
    var arr : [Element] = []
    
    mutating func push(item : Element) -> (){
        arr.append(item)
    }
    
    mutating func pop() -> Element? {
        if count == 0 {
            return nil
        }
        return arr[count - 1]
    }
}

var obj = MyStack<Int>(count : 0)
obj.push(item: 1)
print(obj.arr) // arr = [1]
print(obj.count) //count = 0 Why the value of count is not 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring `count` as a stored property on `MyStack`. Default implementations in protocols are only used by conforming types if the conforming type itself doesn't provide an implementation on its own.

So you need to remove the `count` property from `MyStack` and this way, the default `count` implementation from the `Container` protocol will be used.

```
struct MyStack<Element> : Stack {
    typealias Item = Element
    var arr : [Element] = []
    
    mutating func push(item : Element) -> (){
        arr.append(item)
    }
    
    mutating func pop() -> Element? {
        if count == 0 {
            return nil
        }
        return arr[count - 1]
    }
}

var obj = MyStack<Int>()
obj.push(item: 1)
print(obj.arr) // arr = [1]
print(obj.count) // 1
```

Comment: If I remove `count` from `MyStack`, then it is throwing an error saying `Type 'MyStack<Element>' does not conform to protocol 'Container'`

Comment: @TanmayAgarwal the code in my answer is running perfectly fine using all Swift versions from 4.0 to 5.5, as you can see [here](https://swiftfiddle.com/m5din6wxh5ddxenln4ir7ld7eq). So please double check that you've correctly copied the code from my answer.

Comment: Yeah, got my mistake! Thnx @Dávid Pásztor

Comment: @TanmayAgarwal Glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it. If you're unsure how to do that, you can read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).